# Как правильно добавить класс на JS по клику, если классы-триггеры дублируются?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется список с содержимым внутри.
Как сделать, чтобы класс для `ul.hide-me` добавлялся при клике на `.parent-lm-a`, при этом чтобы это не влияло на аналогичные элементы ниже/выше. 
Обобщая: как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку задавался класс только одному `ul`, а не всем сразу?

```js
 
 $('.parent-div > a').on('click',function(){
    $('.hide-me').toggleClass('show-subchildren');
 });
```

```css
.show-subchildren {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent-ul">
     <li class="first-include">
      <div class="parent-div">
         <a href="#" class="parent-lm-a">Добавить класс по клику только для ul, который ниже меня</a>
         <ul class="hide-me"><li>111</li></ul>
      </div>
     <li>
     <li class="first-include">
      <div class="parent-div">
         <a href="#" class="parent-lm-a">Добавить класс по клику только для ul, который ниже меня</a>
         <ul class="hide-me"><li>111</li></ul>
      </div>
     <li>
    </ul>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('.parent-div').find('.hide-me').toggleClass('show-subchildren');
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]